# Is there a way to have the iPhone suggest corrections but not automatically apply them?

Tags: iphone

The iPhone's autocorrect function is wrong for me more often than not, but I'd still like to see its suggestions and have a way to apply them - they just shouldn't be applied automatically. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

In a nutshell: No (but it would be nice to have)